# Image shape detection in JavaScript

Tags: image-processing, shapes

I'm looking to write a script to look over a series of images that are essentially white canvas with a few black rectangles on them.

[image: image mask]

My question is this: what's the best modus operandi that would identify each of the black rectangles in turn.

Obviously I'd scan the image pixel by pixel and work out if it's colour was black or white. So far so good, Identifying and isolating each rectangle - now that's the tricky part :) A pointer in the right direction would be a great help, thank you.

Comment: In short words, you need to obtain a set of coordinates of rectangles given a BW image? Extract connected components and find bounding box for each component.

Comment: Are you looking for some JS image processing library or for algorithm description? Or you simply need to get thinks done in any way?

Comment: An algorithm description would be useful, if not then pseudo code would suffice

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode on how to use depth first search to mark connected components. Finding bounding boxes will be easy. Ask for clarifications if needed.